# The connection to http://localhost:31735/signalr/connect?... was interrupted while the page was loading

Tags: signalr

In my signalR connection

```
var chat = jQuery.connection.cHATS;
```

each time the page is loaded, the connection is therefore interrupted. Is there a way to stop the connection when the page is loaded or the tab is closed?

Comment: That error seems to be a firefox specific thing. I'm not sure that we can do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Checking the **Network Statistics**? As per David Fowler(The creators of Signalr along with Damien Edwards) mentioned  you can compare the **negotiate** options of Firefox browsers alongside Google Chrome(or **Google Canary** browser, good for developers) or IE 10 with the developer tools and compare the result and see the exact scenario when this error is coming in Firefox browser and other browsers. Add **breakpoints**(VS 2012) and see what you get.